# jQuery: How to hide DIV with slideToggle function

Tags: jquery, hide, slidetoggle

I need to modify following script. When is `.toggle1` clicked and `.area1` displayed, I need to hide `.area1` and show only `.area2`, when `.toggle2` clicked.
Any ideas? Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
  $(".toggle1").click(function() {
    $(".area1").slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".toggle2").click(function() {
    $(".area2").slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle1">btn 1</div>
<div class="toggle2">btn 2</div>

<div class="area1" style="display:none;">Hidden 1</div>

<div class="area2" style="display:none;">Hidden 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go you need to just .[**`hide`**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the respective `textarea` in the click function

See the demo below

```js
$(function() {
  $(".toggle1").click(function() {
    $(".area1").slideToggle();
    $(".area2").hide();
    return false;
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".toggle2").click(function() {
    $(".area2").slideToggle();
    $(".area1").hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle1">btn 1</div>
<div class="toggle2">btn 2</div>

<div class="area1" style="display:none;">Hidden 1</div>

<div class="area2" style="display:none;">Hidden 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question assuming that you meant clicking on toggle1 will only area1 and vice-versa

```
$(function() {
  $(".toggle1").click(function() {
    $(".area1").slideToggle();
        $(".area2").hide();
    return false;
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".toggle2").click(function() {
    $(".area2").slideToggle();
    $(".area1").hide();
    return false;
  });
});`
```

Comment: i was answering, but the previous answer was posted before i could post.